How to add authorization scope to existing Google project for YouTube Data API v3
I run several processes against a few YouTube accounts to gather information about my videos, including video descriptive data, status (views, likes, ...), subscriber lists, gathering chat data and so on.
For all of this, I am using GoogleAuth OAUTH2.0 security, and the following YouTube Data API scope is in play:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Now I want to be able to end an existing livestream (lately, the platform I use for streaming does not reliably end the YT stream, and I need to help it do its job).  This livestream-ending can be accomplished via liveBroadcasts->transform() apparently.  So I need to add at least one of these scopes, according to documentation for that function at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl

At Google Developers Console, I do not see options for adding scopes.
As mentioned above, I have several processes that use the current authorization (via a database maintained internally), and I am not looking to add a new "client" nor a new "project" - just want to increase the allowed function of the existing.
Historically, setting up a new "client" has been a bit of a nightmare here, so I hope that can be avoided.  Setting up new authorization is a confusing area for me, and that step where we have to paste some long value into some web browser does not work well in this environment (all the servers are headless, and no web browser is run on the servers that access this data).  Invariably, project changes involving changes to OAUTH2.0 apps end up breaking apps that have worked for years.  (To be fair, this is likely an education issue, but at the same time the process seems unnecessarily complex.)
What are my options for cleanly obtaining the additional authority required here without breaking the processes that already work?
As a side question, how can I determine if the *readonly scope will interfere with the desire to change the state of a livestream?  Will I need a client that has readonly, and a separate client that does not?  The name "readonly" implies that it cannot be associated with projects that make changes.  But that may simply be a misleading aspect of the name.

In the OAuth Consent Screen section, there is an option to Add or Remove scope.
However, a new client will likely need to be created if a new capability is neeeded.  For the type of processing done here (batch processes - no user interaction), the Client type should be Desktop App.  There can be several clients for one project, each with its own authorization and scope(s).
Testing has shown that scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube is not compatible with scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly, and this is why a new client will amost certainly be needed.  The error message does not come out and say that - instead, it provides a general "invalid scopes" message that lacks details about why the scope is invalid. (Technically, it is not invalid.  The combination is.)  By trial-and-error only, I determined that the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube scope is enough for this task.
Note that combining this https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube scope with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl will cause this error to be raised.  This is in direct conflict with the documentation, which says, "at least one" of these scopes is required.  Truth is, "exactly one" seems to be the only answer that works.
If anyone reading this has a link that points out which scopes are compatible (or not) with others, please post that information in the comments.  Thank you.
